# excel - find and write with adding custom text

Tags: excel, find

I have this table

[image: Table]

which I need is some formula, which can make what is in the red rectangle. It should also work with active filters - like this:

[image: after filter]

and again formula should create that text which is in the red rectangle.

So, basically. Formula should search for non blank cells in specific column, and then write their content in new cell but every record should be separated by "|".

I can find any text in one cell and then write it down:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("",A1)),A1,"")
```

but I dont know how to search in a range, add custom separator and make it working with active filter (here something with SUBTOTAL I suppose).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a VBA function to solve your issue:

[image]

```
Public Function CONCATENATESPECIAL(rng As Range) As String

Dim rng1 As Range

CONCATENATESPECIAL = ""

   For Each rng1 In rng
        If rng1.Value <> "" And rng1.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        CONCATENATESPECIAL = CONCATENATESPECIAL & rng1.Text & " | "
        End If
   Next rng1

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working, but is it possible to make it work with filter active as in the second picture? Use somehow SUBTOTAL? Thanks again.